Condition for Monotonic Phase Increase in $ z^2 + bz + c$ over the Unit Circle
I am studying a quadratic polynomial $P(z) = z^2 + bz + c$ , where $b$ and $c$ are real constants. I want to determine conditions on $b$ and $c$ such that

The phase of $P(z)$ is monotonically increases from $0$ to $\pi$ as $z = e^{j\omega}$ traverses the unit circle from $ \omega = 0 $ to $ \omega = \pi $
The phase of $P(z)$ is monotonically decreases from $0$ to $-\pi$ as $z = e^{j\omega}$ traverses the unit circle from $ \omega = 0 $ to $ \omega = \pi $

Here are some additional points:

By phase, I mean the principle argument of the complex number $ P(e^{j\omega}) $ which lies in $(-\pi,\pi]$.
I am looking for the conditions on the real coefficients $b$ and $c$ that ensure this behavior.

I tried to find the angle for $P(e^{j\omega})$ which has $\frac{y}{x}$ = $\frac{sin(2 \omega)+bsin(\omega)}{cos(2 \omega)+bcos(\omega)+c}$, however taking derivatives and setting the constraints to obtain the condition seems very tedious.
I used desmos and found that maybe keeping $b>2$ allows a range for $c$ in $[-1-b,-1+b]$ which achieves the monotonically increasing condition, however this seems only a subset of the actual condition.
Any insights or approaches to deriving these conditions would be greatly appreciated!
